# R table package with high style modifiability

Tags: r

I would like to output a table as a PDF or HTML.
Since I need to achieve a style very close to [this table style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1x1h.png), I was wondering which package woud allow the **highest amount of modifiability** to achieve this style.The table was taken from [John Lott's 'More Guns, Less Crime'](https://www.hoplofobia.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/MGLC-3rd-Edition.pdf) (p. 351).

Does anyone have recommendations? 
As always, thanks for your help! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: LaTeX and HTML are two very different beasts.

Comment: I know, I know. :) But it is part of a school project: The goal is to achieve this style in R.

Comment: I will give a try to `stargazer`.

Comment: In my experience, tables in LaTeX and html are two different beasts that do not go well together. At least not seamlessly. If you find anything, do let us know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really quite ineperienced and new to R, so I doubt I could provide any useful knowledge but I will try `stargazer` and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WovOi.png), `huxtable` seems the most modifiable. The table was taken from [David Hugh-Jones' comparison page](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html), and David Hugh-Jones is the author of `huxtable`, so I am not sure how impartial it is but it looks solid.

Comment: Hahaha, sine ira et studio!